# SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: tailwindcss/base. >> @import 'tailwindcss/base';

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

**I am getting this log while doing cap deploy cant understand why this issue presist any help?**

this is my capistrano.log file I am pasting

```
   Done in 604ms.
warning ../../package.json: No license field
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
warning webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
warning ../../package.json: No license field
rake aborted!
SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: tailwindcss/base.
        on line 5200:1 of stdin
>> @import 'tailwindcss/base';  

   ^
stdin:5200
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:50:in `render'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in `call'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:30:in `call'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-4.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:182:in `load_from_unloaded'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/sprockets-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
/var/www/beachfireguy/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.2.2/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this is my tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [ 
    './app/**/*.html',
    './app/**/*.erb',
    './app/**/*.js',
    './app/**/*.jsx',
    './app/**/*.ts',
    './app/**/*.tsx',
    './app/**/*.css',
    './app/**/*.scss',
    ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

this is application.tailwind.css

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base'; 
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but I had to add .css extension on these files to make work.

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base.css'; 
@import 'tailwindcss/components.css';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities.css';
```